# Closed - Bootstrap - How to align vertical position of hamburger menu in Bootstrap Studio

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, vertical-alignment, hamburger-menu

I have the following problem: I created a website in Bootstrap Studio with the "Clean Sky"-Template, so my site has this navbar with showing the navbar toggle, when the screen size is smaller than a specific width. When the toggle get visible and I press this button, the upcoming hamburger-menu get trapped and some navbar content resp. hamburger-menu content isn't visible, there should stand "HOME" above "LEISTUNGEN". When I try making it visible, then the links in the normal navbar get changed too.

Here the screen before pressing:

[Before pressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBfy5.png)

Here the visible "cut":

[After pressing the Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK8CM.png)

What could I change in the CSS-Code or what could I code with JavaScript to fix that problem?

EDIT

I don't find the bug exactly, I forgot that I wanted to create a blurred transparent navbar and a carousel under that, so I played with some Margin and Padding settings. Whatever I changed, after recreating the webiste without any Margin and Padding settings changes on the navbar, the hamburger menu works fine now.

Code of the navbar: (anything except the navbar is inside the navbar, don't get fooled by the indent after the second line)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg fixed-top clean-navbar" style="/*background:none;*/background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);background-image:none;z-index:1000;font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;padding:0px;margin:0px;height:70px;width:100%;">
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-primary logo" style="color:#000000;margin-right:16px;padding-left:15px;">Neugart-GmbH</a>
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" class="navbar-toggler" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:15px;font-size:20px;">
        <span class="sr-only" style="/*color:#ff0404;*/">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1" style="background:none;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" style="margin-top:0px;padding-top:0px;">
                <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-primary" style="color:#000000;font-size:13px;">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a href="services.html" class="nav-link text-primary active" style="color:#000000;font-size:13px;">Leistungen</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a href="references.html" class="nav-link text-primary" style="color:#000000;font-size:13px;">Referenzen</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a href="about-us.html" class="nav-link text-primary" style="color:#000000;font-size:13px;">Unser Team</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                <a href="contact-us.html" class="nav-link text-primary" style="color:#000000;font-size:13px;">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip: keep your code clean (in case the code you show here is just for example purposes too) by splitting your styling and structure in a separate file. Create an external style.css file and link to it in your head [explained here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

To solve it you should check and try to modify the item classes by going to the inspector (press F12) in your browser. You will possibly find some other style declarations that conflict with, I think, your < ul>-item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tip. I "found" the bug. When I started to create the website, I wanted a blurred transparent navbar and a bootstrap carousel under that. So I played with some Margins and Paddings and I think I just deleted something or whatever. But after recreating the website without any Margin and Padding changes on the navbar, all works fine.